# Use a variable to select an ActiveX control Checkbox by name (in Word from Excel)?

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, ms-word

## What is wrong with this line of code?

```
WordDoc.CheckBoxNum.Value = CheckBoxVal
```

To be clear, I am working with an ActiveX control "Checkbox".  I have the values (true/false) and checkbox names saved in an Excel file.  The code opens my word document and automatically loops through the checkboxes, setting their values. The fact I am controlling word from Excel may change my objects?

*If they were Form Field... This works--*

```
CheckBoxNum = "Check1"
CheckBoxVal = "True"
WordDoc.FormFields(CheckBoxNum).CheckBox.Value = CheckBoxVal
```

## Here is my whole code

```
Sub Doit()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Dim WordDoc As Object
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim CheckBoxNum As String
    Dim CheckBoxVal As String
    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer

    'Open Word
    filepath = "C:\test.docx"
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("word.application")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(filepath)

    'Editing
    Range("a1").Select 'first value
    i = 0
    For i = 0 To 6 ' number of rows in table 
          'get from excel
          CheckBoxNum = ActiveCell.Offset(i, k + 1).Value
          CheckBoxVal = ActiveCell.Offset(i, k).Value

           'put to word
           WordDoc.CheckBoxNum.Value = CheckBoxVal '<-- HELP!
    Next i

    '// CLEAN UP //
    WordDoc.Application.ActiveDocument.Save
    WordDoc.Close
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately we cannot refer to an ActiveX control directly by its name using `WordDoc.InlineShapes(CheckBoxNum)`, this only works if we know its index number: `WordDoc.InlineShapes(1)`.

This means that you have to loop through all the controls, comparing its `OLEFormat.Object.Name` to the name you are looking for:

```
Dim obj As Object

For i = 0 To 6 ' number of rows in table
    'get from excel
    CheckBoxNum = ActiveCell.Offset(i, k + 1).Value
    CheckBoxVal = ActiveCell.Offset(i, k).Value

    For Each obj In WordDoc.InlineShapes
        If obj.OLEFormat.Object.Name = CheckBoxNum Then
            obj.OLEFormat.Object.Value = CheckBoxVal
        End If
    Next obj
Next i
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. I ended up moving the For Each loop into a function to get a more clean code - but this solution really nailed it for me

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can use:

```
WordDoc.InlineShapes(CheckBoxNum).OLEFormat.Object.Value = CheckBoxVal
```