# Improve 33 checkbox code subs to few? (Checkbox for auto-date in bookmarks)

Tags: vba, ms-word, activex

:)
Im new to VBA!
I have a working code for inserting date where i have a bookmark when using a checkbox (ActiveX). Problem is i have 33 checkboxes (I actually wish for 33x2. one for yes and one for no). So i ended up with 33 Subs and 33 bookmarks. I bet this code can be more efficient braking it down to just a few subs. Annyone has anny idea if it can be done?
The code under is the first of 33 repeating subs where Sub and bookmark name is agi1, agi2 agi3.....

```
Private Sub agi1_Click()

Dim rngFormat As Range
 Set rngFormat = ActiveDocument.Range( _
 Start:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("agi1").Range.Start, _
 End:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("agi1").Range.End)
 With rngFormat
 .Font.Size = 8
 End With

   Dim v
   Dim BMRange As Range
   v = ThisDocument.agi1.Value

'Sjekke om boks er sjekket eller ikke
   If v = True Then

'Sett inn dato i bokmerke
Set BMRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("agi1").Range
With Selection.Font
 .Size = 9
End With
BMRange.Text = (Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy"))

Else

'Erstatte dato med tom tekst hvis boks ikke er sjekket
Set BMRange = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("agi1").Range
BMRange.Text = " "

End If
'Sett inn bokmerke på nytt
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "agi1", BMRange

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the code the same, apart from the bookmarks etc?  There is event sinking and I believe `application.caller` could help, if your button names are in line with the bookmarks.

Comment: Yes. Only difference is the name of the checkbox and bookmark (i used same name for both) . One bookmark for each ckeckbox. Thankyou, i will "check it out". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveX controls always register their event handlers like so:

```
Private Sub NameOfTheControl_NameOfTheEvent({args})
```

If you rename the handler, the control stops working - because the *name* of the handler *must* be formed as above, with an underscore separating the name of the control and the name of the handled event.

So if your controls must exist at compile-time, there's no way around it: for 33 controls you need 33 handlers.

That doesn't mean you need that huge procedure repeated 33 times!

Extract a procedure. Select the entire body of that handler, cut it.

Now make a new procedure prototype:

```
Private Sub HandleCheckBoxClick(ByVal controlName As String)

End Sub
```

And paste the body in there. Then replace all the places you have a hard-coded `"agi1"` with a reference to this `controlName` parameter:

```
Dim rngFormat As Range
Set rngFormat = ActiveDocument.Range( _
    Start:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(controlName).Range.Start, _
    End:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(controlName).Range.End)
With rngFormat
    .Font.Size = 8
End With

'...
```

The places where you're referring to the control using its programmatic name will be a bit harder:

```
v = ThisDocument.agi1.Value
```

You can get the `MSForms.CheckBox` control through the `ThisDocument.InlineShapes` collection, but [that won't let you find a checkbox by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089416/1188513), so you need a function that can do it for you:

```
Private Function FindCheckBoxByName(ByVal controlName As String) As MSForms.CheckBox
    Dim sh As InlineShape
    For Each sh In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
        If TypeOf sh.OLEFormat.Object Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If sh.OLEFormat.Object.Name = controlName Then
                'return the MSForms control:
                Set FindControlByName = sh.OLEFormat.Object
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

And now you can do this:

```
Dim cb As MSForms.ChecBox
Set cb = FindCheckBoxByName(controlName)
If cb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "No ActiveX CheckBox control named '" & controlName & "' was found in ThisDocument."
    Exit Sub
End If
v = cb.Value
```

Once all references to the ActiveX control are parameterized, your 33 handlers can now look like this:

```
Private Sub agi1_Click()
    HandleCheckBoxClick "agi1"
End Sub

Private Sub agi2_Click()
    HandleCheckBoxClick "agi2"
End Sub

'...

Private Sub agi33_Click()
    HandleCheckBoxClick "agi33"
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could have the checkboxes created at run-time, and then have their `Click` event handled in a dedicated class module, but that's a little bit more involved ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Im trying to make it work. (Im new at this) but i cant seem to quite get it. The function, i put it after the HandleCheckBoxClick sub? 
And the part after the function. Does it fo inside the function or inside the HandleCheckBoxClick sub? I will post the code i have so far from what i understand.

Comment: @HerlandBjørnsbror the function is on its own, you can't have nested procedure scopes in VBA. The `HandleCheckBoxClick` procedure needs to contain all the code you currently have in your 33 handlers, but parameterized.

Comment: I had an error at: For Each sh ThisDocument.InlineShapes
It was asking for In. So i added it: For Each sh In ThisDocument.InlineShapes

Answer (score 1):

You could use event sinking, maybe to.

In an normal module, create a collection and populate it to hold the classes that will control the check box events.

In this have the code, this will need to be run on opening the document, something early in it's life to populate the collection.

```
Public col As Collection

Public Sub SETUP()

Dim o As InlineShape
Dim c As MSForms.CheckBox
Dim cust As clsCustomCheckBox

Set col = New Collection

For Each o In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes

    Set c = o.OLEFormat.Object
    Set cust = New clsCustomCheckBox
    cust.INIT c
    col.Add cust

Next o

End Sub
```

and then have a class module called `clsCustomCheckBox` and have it's code as

```
Private WithEvents c As MSForms.CheckBox

Public Function INIT(cmdIN As MSForms.CheckBox)
    Set c = cmdIN
End Function

Private Sub c_Click()
    MsgBox "Here you can get the name " & c.Name
End Sub
```

This will divert each checkbox click to the classes `c_click` rather than it's own.

So for you

```
Dim rngFormat As Range
 Set rngFormat = ActiveDocument.Range( _
 Start:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(c.name).Range.Start, _
 End:=ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(c.name).Range.End)
 With rngFormat
 .Font.Size = 8
 End With
.......
```

Comment: This would be the preferred way to go about it. Didn't want to get into `WithEvents` and class modules though, but OP should definitely look into this.

Comment: Cool. I shure will. Than you Nathan_Sav